# Dax Query to Calculate Cp Cpk using sigma estimator as sbar/c4 in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

i am in a very peculiar requirement of calculating cp cpk in powerbi using the formula for sigma estimator as "sbar/c4"  check reference link [here](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/19/help-and-how-to/quality-and-process-improvement/capability-analysis/supporting-topics/data-and-data-assumptions/using-subgroups-to-assess-capability/#:%7E:text=Subgroups%20should%20be%20representative%20of,process%20you%20want%20to%20evaluate.&text=Therefore%2C%20when%20you%20estimate%20the,be%20independent%20of%20each%20other)

My sample data is as given below

| DATE | Country Name | State Type | State Name | City Lable | PO Box No | Box Size | READINGS | Value | LSL | USL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06-10-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.31 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 09-10-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.428 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 16-10-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.364 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 19-10-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.48 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 22-10-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.49 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 28-10-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.407 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 01-11-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.512 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 17-11-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.506 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 19-11-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.472 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 21-11-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.507 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 22-11-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.596 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 19-12-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.517 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 21-12-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.529 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 22-12-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.481 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 23-12-2019 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.634 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 01-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.451 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 02-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.375 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 03-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.403 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 06-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.404 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 07-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.54 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 10-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.614 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 12-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.668 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 13-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.548 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 16-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.497 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 25-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.577 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 26-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.517 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 28-01-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap191002 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.481 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 09-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.499 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 15-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.429 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 17-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.347 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 17-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.59 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 19-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.433 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 22-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.478 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 26-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.569 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 29-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.701 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 29-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.496 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 30-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.548 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 31-03-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.604 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 01-04-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.558 | 18.2 | 18.8 |
| 02-04-2020 | Dummy | Gaon | 37 | Cap200303 | 1 | 10 | READING7 | 18.63 | 18.2 | 18.8 |

here we need to calculate cp cpk for city lable column as subgroup,... since this is a sample but in reality there would be 1000s of city lables, 10 different country names, 40 state names. PO box no, Readings and Box size is to be ignored

C4 value is decided to be 0.9727 as subgroups is considered to be 10

i want to know how do i create a dax query to calculate the new sigma value

my current query is like this

```
    Cpk  = 
VAR sigma = STDEV.S(Table[Value])
VAR estimatedMean = AVERAGE(Table[Value])
VAR Cplower = (estimatedMean-MIN(Table[LSL Value]))/(3*sigma)
VAR Cpupper = (MAX(Table[USL Value])-estimatedMean)/(3*sigma)
RETURN MIN(Cplower,Cpupper)
```

the new query can dymically change as per slicers selected in Powerbi eg country, state type, state name etc

PLease help me out, condition is very critical

Comment: What is failing with your current approach?  Can you example your expected output?  Are you able to reduce the dataset down to the smallest practical set for replicating the issue?

Comment: Currently i am calculating the sigma value as std deviation of sample but i need to use the formula of Sbar / c4  where Sbar is the average of standard deviations of all the subgroups. here the subgroup would mean City Lable